# Why isn't `use std::io` enough here?

Tags: rust

I tried to compile the following program:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    io::stdout().write(b"Please enter your name: ");
    io::stdout().flush();
}
```

Unfortunately, compiler resisted:

```
error: no method named `write` found for type `std::io::Stdout` in the current scope
 --> hello.rs:4:18
  |
4 |     io::stdout().write(b"Please enter your name: ");
  |                  ^^^^^
  |
  = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope; the following trait is implemented but not in scope, perhaps add a `use` for it:
  = help: candidate #1: `use std::io::Write`
```

I found that I needed to do `use std::io::{self, Write};`. What does `use std::io;` actually do then and how do (if possible) I pull all names defined in `std::io`? Also, would it be a bad style?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What does `use std::io;` actually do then?

It does what every use-statement does: makes the last part of the used path directly available (pulling it into the current namespace). That means that you can write `io` and the compiler knows that you mean `std::io`.

> How do I pull all names defined in `std::io`?

With `use std::io::*;`. This is commonly referred to as *glob-import*.

> Also, would it be a bad style?

Yes, it would. Usually you should avoid glob-imports. They can be handy for certain situations, but cause a lot of trouble on most cases. For example, there is also the trait `std::fmt::Write`... so importing everything from `fmt` and `io` would possibly result in name-clashes. Rust values explicitness over implicitness, so rather avoid glob-imports.

However, there is one type of module that is usually used with a glob-import: preludes. And in fact, there is even a `std::io::prelude` which reexports important symbols. See [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/prelude/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Why do I need to pull in write but not flush though? Also, aren't those methods of stdout/stdin?

Comment: `write()` and `flush()` are methods of [the `Write` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html). Therefore you just have to use that trait. `Stdout` is a type which *implements* the `Write` trait. The method signature is given by the trait, the implementation by the type itself. Does this clarify the issue? :)

Comment: So `use std::io;` pulls types, but not traits?

Comment: No, as I said `use std::io;` pulls the name `io` (which is a module). It doesn't import any items from that module, neither traits nor types.